The service collection cannot be modified because it is read-only
I am using ASP.NET Core 8. I'm trying to resolve a dependency at app start up and then use it to manually register a second dependency.
But I am getting this error

The service collection cannot be modified because it is read-only

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// REGISTER FIRST DEPENDENCY
builder.Services.AddTransient<IMyDependency, MyDependency>(); 

var app = builder.Build();

using (var serviceScope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;

    // RESOLVE FIRST DEPENDENCY
    var myDependency = services.GetRequiredService<IMyDependency>(); 

    // ERROR: The service collection cannot be modified because it is read-only
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IAnotherDependency>(srv => new AnotherDependency(myDependency));
}

How could I get this to work?

Register the second dependency where you did the first one. Resolving the dependencies later is the whole point of this all.


Why occurring this error:

In ASP.NET Core, IServiceCollection is used to register various services within the application. Once the BuildServiceProvider() method is called to construct an IServiceProvider, the IServiceCollection becomes read-only. This is done to ensure that service registrations cannot be modified or disrupted during the runtime of the application.

Solution：

Services are added to the DI container with WebApplicationBuilder.Services, builder.Services. You can achieve this just need to register them both in the container.
You can register the IMyDependency service first, then register the IAnotherDependency service. Use a lambda expression as a parameter during the registration of IAnotherDependency to resolve the IMyDependency service. This way, you can implement the instantiation of IAnotherDependency which depends on the IMyDependency service：
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddTransient<IMyDependency, MyDependency>(); // REGISTER FIRST DEPENDENCY

builder.Services.AddTransient<IAnotherDependency>(srv =>
{
    var myDependency = srv.GetRequiredService<IMyDependency>(); // resolve first dependency
    return new AnotherDependency(myDependency);
});

var app = builder.Build();


What you are trying to do is not supported, and for good reasons. You have to register everything at once. For instance:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddTransient<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IAnotherDependency, AnotherDependency>(); 

var app = builder.Build();


I had the same issue and I realized it was occurring because I was trying to register the services after calling  builder.build().
Solution:
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


// add the data base connection
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TodoDb>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList"));

// register other services here

// then call build
WebApplication app = builder.Build();

